# How to pass PORT's Google Cloud environment variable to Play Framework server

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, playframework, dockerfile

I have started using `Google Cloud Platform` so I can deploy my `Scala Play Framework` project. I am using `docker` to create a `docker image` which I am pushing to Google Cloud Platform and running it using `Cloud Run`. The docker image is running successfully on my local machine, but when I try to deploy it on google, I get this error:

> Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then
>   listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for
>   this revision might contain more information.

I have read `Play 2.7's` documentation and I got to this Dockerfile:

```
FROM aa8y/sbt:0.13.15

COPY ./target/universal/scalatry-1.0.zip .

RUN unzip scalatry-1.0.zip

COPY ./main_route .

CMD scalatry-1.0/bin/scalatry -Dhttp.port=${PORT}
```

so basically, I am trying to run the zipped project file (which I have created by using `scala dist`) and run the executable on `/bin/scalatry` by passing the `${PORT}` variable which will be passed once the project runs on google. This does not seem to work.

Another try I have done is going to my `application.conf` file and adding:
`play.server.http.port = ${PORT}` but it did not have any impact either, this error keeps popping up.

Do you have any work around? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the environment variable in Cloud Run using following command:

```
gcloud run deploy [SERVICE] --image gcr.io/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE] --update-env-vars KEY1=VALUE1,KEY2=VALUE2
```

So you would run something like

```
gcloud run deploy [YOUR-SERVICE-NAME] --image gcr.io/[PROJECT-ID]/[DOCKER-IMAGE] --update-env-vars PORT=PORTNUMBER
```

You can read more about how to use environment variable in CLoud Run here: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/environment-variables

Hope this helps.